# bash merge lines that start and end the same

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

dudes, how can I turn this file:

```
ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home 7700480  602202 7098278    8% /home
ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   512000     471  511529    1% /tmp
ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-var   512000    3236  508764    1% /var
ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home   58G   26G   30G  47% /home
ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   3.9G  2.3G  1.5G  61% /tmp
ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-var   3.9G  533M  3.2G  15% /var
ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home 3424256  250425 3173831    8% /home
ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   262144      17  262127    1% /tmp
ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-var   262144    2647  259497    2% /var
ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home   52G  9.5G   40G  20% /home
ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   4.0G  137M  3.7G   4% /tmp
ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-var   4.0G  419M  3.4G  11% /var
```

into this one:

```
ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home 7700480  602202 7098278    8% /home   ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home   58G   26G   30G  47% /home
ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   512000     471  511529    1% /tmp    ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   3.9G  2.3G  1.5G  61% /tmp
ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-var   512000    3236  508764    1% /var    ops01.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-var   3.9G  533M  3.2G  15% /var
ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home 3424256  250425 3173831    8% /home   ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-home   52G  9.5G   40G  20% /home
ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   262144      17  262127    1% /tmp    ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-tmp   4.0G  137M  3.7G   4% /tmp
ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-var   262144    2647  259497    2% /var    ops02.mysite.com /dev/mapper/sys-var   4.0G  419M  3.4G  11% /var
```

So when the directorie is the same, merge that lines
(in OSX the df command outputs the inodes and space usage, but in this redhat that I'm using I had to run one df -h for the space usage, and one df -i to get the inodes usage)

I have used:

```
cat file | sed 's/[0-9]% /*\n/ /'
```

Trying to replace the text after every '%'for the text in the next line... but that didn't work at all... :S
and I just can't filter by 'ops01.mysite.com' because I don't know how many servers I have to check.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

run the 2 `df` commands separately, saving their results to separate files, then `join` the two files.

```
df > df-size
df -i > df-inodes
join df-size df-inodes
```

Comment: bash one liner: join <(df) <(df -i)

Comment: That would be okay, but I need to report this way:
`Filesystem` `SpaceSize` `SpaceUsed` `SpaceAvail` `SpaceCapacity` `iused` `ifree` `%iused` `MountedOn`, so if the lines could be merged then that would be a matter of `awk {choose your columns}`

Comment: @dimba your one Liner is giving me results :D, Maybe I don't need to fight that much to get this done :D thanks `:D` `:D` `:D`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{a[$1$2]=a[$1$2]" "$0;next}END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}' your_file
```

check [here](http://ideone.com/f8d6cs)